# Python 3 Elif Indentation Error

Tags: python, indentation

I am working on a simple script in Python, and when I attempt to use an elif statement, it throws an error saying that it expected an indented block. I know this may be something simple, but I have tried everything and I am stuck, so anyone willing to help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

```
import math as m

mass = input("Enter the mass of the object (kg)")
i = 0
while i == 0:
  if type(mass)!= type(1.1):
    #mass = input("You have entered an incorrect value, please enter a numerical value.")

  elif type(mass) == type(1.1):
    print("test")
    break
```

The full error message is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9
    elif type(mass) == type(1.1):
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: You need to have some code in your `if` block. At least a `pass`.

Comment: Comments are thrown away by the interpreter, essentially leaving nothing after the if block.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need `elif` here; just `else` will do. (And things generally read better when you put the affirmative case first.)

Comment: Right, thank you kindall.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` is empty (as comments are ignored), therefore Python expects a statement to execute in the `True` case in the next not-commented line with a indentation.

Just put a `pass` in the `if` block, in order to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a code block after the if statement, you cannot have an if statement and directly jump to the elif condition